# Implementing a sub-function with va_list and va_arg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a varargs-style function that I want to split out to a va_list-style sub-function.  The original function:

```
void container_append(container_t *c, element_t *element, ...) {
  element_t *e;
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, element);
  while((e = va_arg(ap, element_t *)) != NULL) {
    container_append_aux(c, e);
  }
  va_end(ap);
}
```

Note that the caller must terminate the list of elements with a NULL, but that should not cause any problems.  Refactored:

```
void container_append(container_t *c, element_t *element, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, element);
  container_vappend(c, ap);
  va_end(ap);
}

void container_vappend(container_t *c, va_list ap) {
  element_t *e;
  while ((e = va_arg(ap, element_t *)) != NULL) {
    container_append_aux(c, e);
  }
}
```

However, when I call it like this:

```
container_append(c, NULL);
```

... inside of `container_vappend()`, the call to `va_arg()` is returning something that isn't NULL.

This is a transcription of a more complicated function, but barring any typos, did I miss something in the setup or usage of `va_list` and `va_arg()`?

Comment: You're ignoring `element`.

Comment: @tkausl: Can you expand on your comment?  I thought `va_start(ap, element)` (in the caller) would set up va_arg to return `element` first.  Maybe it doesn't work that way?

Comment: Remove `element` from the argument list, and `va_start(ap, c)`. `va_start` sets up `va_arg` to fetch the first item *after* the named parameter.

Comment: @user3386109 N.B. `va_start(ap, X)` is only well-defined when X is the _last_ named parameter.

Comment: @zwol If there's only one named parameter, then it is necessarily the last. Which is why my comment starts with *"Remove `element` ..."* You need to take the comment as a whole, not just nitpick about parts that you've taken out of context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `container_append` is called like this

> ```
> container_append(c, NULL);
> ```

the named parameter `element` will be 0, and there won't be any anonymous parameters.  Under those conditions, `container_append` must not call `va_arg` *at all*, or the program has undefined behavior.  It happened to work by accident before you refactored the code, but the original code is just as buggy as the refactored version.

You can either check `element` before the loop...

```
void
container_append(container_t *c, element_t *element, ...)
{
    if (!element) return;

    container_append_aux(c, element);

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, element);
    while ((element = va_arg(ap, element_t *)))
        container_append_aux(c, element);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

... or you can make all of the element arguments be anonymous:

```
void
container_append(container_t *c, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, c);

    element_t *e;
    while ((e = va_arg(ap, element_t *)))
        container_append_aux(c, e);

    va_end(ap);
}
```

The latter structure is more compatible with the `vappend` refactor you want to do.

---

EDIT: Regarding this query in a comment:

> I thought `va_start(ap, element)` (in the caller) would set up va_arg to return element first. Maybe it doesn't work that way?

Indeed, it does not work that way.  `va_start` sets up `va_arg` to return the first of the *anonymous* arguments.  If there weren't any anonymous arguments, then you walk off the end the very first time you call `va_arg`, and trigger UB.

Comment: Ah! Got it.  `va_start()` needs a real argument from the arglist so it knows where to point to in the call stack.  `va_arg` starts on the first argument _after_ that given argument, i.e. the first _anonymous_ argument.  Very clear now -- thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to issued identified well by [@zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811737/2410359) ...

`container_append(c, one or more arguments, NULL);` is potential *undefined behavior* (UB).

`container_append()` expects a `element_t *element` and `NULL` may be simply `0`.

> `NULL` which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant ...
>
> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.

`NULL` is not specified even to be the same size as a pointer.

`va_arg(ap, element_t *)` is then UB.

To make a safer call, use `container_append(c, args, (element_t *) NULL);`

Comment: @user3386109 With `foo(some_object *p);`, using `foo(NULL);` is OK as `NULL` to converted to a pointer.  With `container_append(c, some args, NULL)`, `NULL` is not converted and so it value with its original type, such as `int` is passed.  `container_append(container_t *c, element_t *element, ...)` does not _know_ that its definition will be using the ... arguments such as `NULL` as a pointer.

Comment: @ chux I reviewed the section on default argument promotions, and it seems that you are correct. `NULL` pointers passed to functions with variable argument lists must be cast to the correct type.

Comment: I won't downvote this answer, but I will point out that it's not relevant to the OP: my question really wasn't about the semantics of NULL.  In fact, in production code, I use a typedef cast along the lines of (element_t *)NULL

Comment: @user3386109 it is more the fact that it doesn't have to be a null pointer at all but null pointer constant such as 0 is equally ok. And this is the only definition that is going to work in C++...

Comment: fearless_fool This answer is relevant to what is posted in the question.  "... the caller must terminate the list of elements with a NULL, but that should not cause any problems." is incorrect as this answer points out the potential  problems with `NULL`.  True. it may not apply to different code not posted here.  It is good that  @zwol found some  problems with the code - there were more..